# How to correctly install new font in Windows 10 in C# winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, windows-10

I need to install new font from my Winforms C# application. I found a lot of posts how to install programmatically new font in windows, so as result have written following code and it works in any version of windows except Win 10:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        //Some ttf file in current folder where app resides
        string fontName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];
        //Name of the font
        string name = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2];            

        var newPath = Path.Combine(WindowsFontsFolder, fontName);

        File.Move(fontName, newPath);
        var result = AddFontResource(newPath);
        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (error != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to AddFontResource");
            return;
        }

        //Add font's record to the registry
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.
            CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts");
        key.SetValue(name + " (TrueType)", fontName);
        key.Close();

        //WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x001D
        SendBroadcastMessageTimeout(0x001D, 5000);
    }
```

After executing this code, for example I install font from file "4427267.ttf" with name parameter "elektra", I open WordPad and see that Font added to the WordPad but with an empty name in the fonts list. 
[image]

And if I select my new font in the list then text in the document does not changed. But after reboot  Windows font works fine. Moreover if I installing fonts with NSIS installer then fonts installed ok and work fine:

```
System::Call 'kernel32::GetSystemWindowsDirectory(t .r0, i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN})'

${File} "" ${fontToInstallFile}
${CopyFiles}  "$INSTDIR\${fontToInstallFileName}" "$0\Fonts\${fontToInstallFileName}"

System::Call "GDI32::AddFontResourceW(t) i ('$0\Fonts\${fontToInstallFileName}') .s"

WriteRegStr HKLM "${fontkey}" "FontName (TrueType)" "${fontToInstallFileName}"

SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
```

But there is no visible difference between NSIS script logic and my winforms C# app code logic. NSIS code works but c# does not. Both codes executed with Administrator rights.

Comment: Bizarrely, Microsoft has never documented how to properly install fonts.  They insist that users should use the Control Panel > Fonts applet.  Using the Process class with the "Install" verb would be the blessed way.  One obvious detail you are not taking care of is writing the registry key for both 32-bit and 64-bit apps.  Google "wow6432node" to learn more.